# IE throws error on if statement

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have no idea why on IE, the code reports an error. Here is the code:

```
if ($size === null) {
    $sizeFolder = '48x48';
} else $sizeFolder = $size+'x'+$size;
```

The error is as follows:

```
SCRIPTING1006: ')' expected
```

IE will set a `)` here like this :

```
if ($size === null)) {
    $sizeFolder = '48x48';
} else $sizeFolder = $size+'x'+$size;
```

but this is still not working. Why is IE reporting an error?

here is the complete Code :

```
    $.ttMessageBox.getIcon = function ($icon,$size=null) {
  var $_icons = Array('[Information]','[Error]','[Question]','[OK]');
  if ($size === null) {
    $sizeFolder = '48x48';
  } else $sizeFolder = $size+'x'+$size; 
  $result = '';
  $Icon = $_icons.indexOf($icon);
  switch ($Icon) {
    case 0: $result += '<img src="/img/icons/'+$sizeFolder+'/dialog_information.png" />';
              break;
    case 1: $result += '<img src="/img/icons/'+$sizeFolder+'/dialog_error.png" />';
              break;
    case 2: $result += '<img src="/img/icons/'+$sizeFolder+'/dialog_question.png" />';
              break;
    case 3: $result += '<img src="/img/icons/'+$sizeFolder+'/dialog_check.png" />';
              break;
    default: $result += '';
  }
return $result;
}
```

Comment: It may be expecting brackets around the else statement.

Comment: Your error is somewhere else in the script before that code as this works just fine and the syntax is valid. Please post the entire script file.

Comment: You have a double closing bracket on your if `if ($size === null)) {`,  try -> `if ($size === null) {`

Comment: @Keith No, that’s not his actual code. That’s what he tried to fix the error.

Comment: Oh, indeed,.. I thought it was my age, and double vision.. :)

Comment: That code looks like PHP, not Javascript. Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: @duskwuff variables starting with `$` are valid in JavaScript.

Comment: @vlaz I know, but it's stylistically unusual, which makes me wonder.

Comment: Post Full code. What other browsers you tried ?

Comment: @JeremyJackson Why would it expect that? And even if it did, why would that cause it to complain about `)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the working code now :

```
$.ttMessageBox.getIcon = function ($icon,$size) {
  var $_icons = Array('[Information]','[Error]','[Question]','[OK]');
  if (typeof $size === "undefined") {
    $sizeFolder = '48x48';
  } else $sizeFolder = $size+'x'+$size;
```

thanks to @Luke Woodward

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
   $.ttMessageBox.getIcon = function ($icon,$size=null) {
```

IE does not support default values for function parameters.  You can't have the `=null` bit.